# Проход по вектору с шагом и подсчёт элементов

Tags: c++, vector

Есть вектор. Допустим `vec=[0.1,0.2,0.8,23.1,0.1,0.2]`. Есть шаг, допустим `h=0.1` от нуля до `m`(в общем случае просто максимальный элемент в векторе, который обходим) нужно пройти по всему вектору посчитать сколько раз встречается элемент соответствующий текущему шагу и записать итоговое количество в другой вектор.
Я сделал это так:

```
        double j=0;
B:


        int i=0;
        int n=0;
        for(j; j<=m; j=j+step)
        {

    A:
            for(i; i<=vec.size; i++)
            {
                if(vec[i]=j && i<vec.size())
                {
                    n++;
                    goto A;
                }
                else(i==vec.size())
                {
                    vec1.pushback(n);
                    goto B;
                }
            }
        }
```

Больше чем уверен, что это ужасно. Подскажите, есть ли более "грамотный" вариант?

Comment: `go to A;` и `go to B;` о_О

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например как-то так:

```
std::vector<double> vec = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 23.1, 0.1, 0.2 };
std::vector<int> result;

const double m = 10;
const double step = 0.1;

for (double j = 0; j <= m; j += step)
    result.push_back(std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](double v) {return std::fabs(v - j) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();}));
```

Comment: Из-за погрешностей при сравнении будет выдавать винигрет

Comment: да уж, надо было подольше погуглить, даже стыдно. спасибо большое

Comment: @gdg согласен, добавил погрешность.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian все равно выдает какую-то кашу

Comment: @bronstein87 разместите например на https://ideone.com/ ваш код, чтобы запустить можно было, посмотреть.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian а, да, всё работает, извините. Вас не затруднит объяснить почему выбрана именно такая погрешность?

Comment: @bronstein87 если по простому - то от балды, вам по своей задаче лучше подобрать. Минимальное значение - DBL_EPSILON в случае использования типа double и FLT_EPSILON в случае float.

Comment: @bronstein87 если хвост дробной части ограничен, то проще домножить на 10^n и работать уже с целочисленной арифметикой.